# Linear model performs better on non-linear classification

Tags: pca, linear

I'm working on the following dataset :
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/gene+expression+cancer+RNA-Seq

I start by looking at PCA/TSNE/UMAP to have a first sight, on all the data using the following code :

```
# Prepare plots
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(20,8))

# remove sample name and scale
#df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)

# PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
         , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, label[['Class']]], axis = 1)#add cancer type 
sns.scatterplot(principalComponents[:,0], principalComponents[:,1], hue=label['Class'], legend='full', ax=ax1)

# TSNE
fashion_tsne = TSNE().fit_transform(x)
sns.scatterplot(fashion_tsne[:,0], fashion_tsne[:,1], hue=label['Class'], legend='full', ax=ax2)

# UMAP
reducer = umap.UMAP()
embedding = reducer.fit_transform(x)
sns.scatterplot(embedding[:,0], embedding[:,1], hue=label['Class'], legend='full',ax=ax3)

plt.show()
```

I get this :

[image: PCA/TSNE/UMAP resultsx]

As i want to create a classification model I start by using a decision tree, from looking at the PCA it seems that the data are non-linearly separable so I expect the decision tree to perform better than logistic regression :

```
# Create training and testing datasets
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, list(label.Class), test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

# Create and fit decision tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=depth, min_samples_leaf=min_leaf)
clf = clf.fit(train_features, train_labels)

# predict
predicted_label = clf.predict(test_features)

# present results
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, test_features, test_labels,
                                 display_labels=list(set(list(label.Class))),
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize='true')

# print accuracy
scores = cross_val_score(clf, x_marker_100, list(label.Class), cv=300)
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f \n \n \n" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
print(classification_report(test_labels, predicted_label))
```

[image: tree results]

but when I try the logistic regression using the following code :

```
# Create training and testing datasets
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, list(label.Class), test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

# Create and fit decision tree
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(train_features, train_labels)


# Predict
predicted_label = clf.predict(test_features)

print(confusion_matrix(test_labels, predicted_label))
print(clf.score(test_features, test_labels))
# present results
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, test_features, test_labels,
                                 display_labels=list(set(list(label.Class))),
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize='true')
plt.show()
# print accuracy
scores = cross_val_score(clf, x_marker_100, list(label.Class), cv=300)
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f \n \n \n" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
```

I get the following confusion matrix :

[image: confusion logistic]

Does this mean that, unlike what i thought from looking at the PCA, my data is linearly separable ? Or is there a problem in the code ?

After doing some feature extraction (going from 20 000+ genes to only 10) PCA seems to show that the problem is almost linear now :

[image: PCA after feature extraction]

however logistic regression performs worst:
[image: logistic on feature extracted]

than the decision tree :
[image: decision tree on feature extracted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA dropped to 2 comps to produce the plots. The data could be linearly separable in higher dimensionality, which is probably the case if we look at the accuracy of your linear regression. The difference between the scores, which is minimal (1 instance classified differently in some cases) can be attributed to things such as parameters for your decision tree, however what's confusing here is that you first applied train_test_split to seperate the data in train and test sets and later the scores were produced by CV. Did you apply that CV to your train set? CV fits your classifier from the beggining and uses 300 subsets of data to predict the rest. That has a stochastic component to it so small differences could be explained by that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should have think about other PC ! As you can see i'm a beginner in ML.  I applied the function cross_val_score on my all dataset, not on the training set. Using CV, should I discard train_test_split, use cv and see the score ?

Comment: Yes! CV is for that job to get an accurate estimate of the accuracy. Extremely useful when we do not have a large dataset. Leave one out CV is the most powerful estimate however it takes a lot of time to train and predict so it is not very common. You are doing great, keep going.